# Generate computed (virtual) column in HSQL from an XML (CLOB) type

Tags: java, xml, oracle, xquery, hsqldb

I have an application which uses **Oracle database** and I'm using **XML typed** columns for storing XML data.
I have some **virtual columns which using XQuery** for get a particular value of a XML typed columns and store it.
It's working fine.

Just for more understanding, let's imagine an applications which stores media contents and have a TITLE virtual column:

```
CREATE TABLE MEDIA_OBJECT
(
    ...
    XML XMLTYPE ,
    TITLE AS ( UPPER(XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('/movies/movie/@title' PASSING XML RETURNING CONTENT) AS VARCHAR2(32))) ) VIRTUAL ,
    ...
)
```

The problem is that I would like to create **Unit and Integration tests** which using **in-memory database**.
I have tried the HSQLDB and everything is working fine except I can't run XQuery to get data from an XML typed columns.

My question is, how is it possible in the HSQLDB? If it's not possible, is it possible in any other free in-memory database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HSQLDB you can access the contents of an XML object via JDBC, using this interface.

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCSQLXML.html

Comment: Thank you!
I have 2 questions regarding to this:
1. Actually I already saw this class before, but it tells about the XML type. In HSQLDB there is no XML type, I store my data in CLOB type.
Is it working with this type as well?

2. This is Java-side solution, not DB-side. Is there a DB side solution (like for the Oracle DB what I mentioned)?

Comment: It allows you to access a column that is in CLOB type as XML. It is indeed a JDBC class. Currently there is no internal DB access to XML fields.